# Check if an element is included in two different arrays

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create a simple calculator to show which of the ints are included in two arrays,all of which numbers are typed by the user.How do i get the full number because I think when i do foreach loop its reading the numbers like for example 49 it reads it as 4 and 9 not 49?How do I solve this problem?Also where am I mistaken?

```
string firstTextBox = ConjTextBox.Text;
string secondTextBox = DisjTextBox.Text;
int intsInFirstTextBox;
int intsInSecondTextBox;
List<int> ListOfInts = new List<int>();
try
{
    foreach (char c in firstTextBox)
    {
        intsInFirstTextBox = Convert.ToInt32(c);
        foreach (char q in secondTextBox)
        {
            intsInSecondTextBox = Convert.ToInt32(q);

            if (intsInFirstTextBox == intsInSecondTextBox)
            {
                ListOfInts.Add(intsInFirstTextBox);
                ListOfInts.Sort();
            }
        }
    }
    foreach (int i in ListOfInts)
    {
        resultTextBox.Text += i.ToString();
    }
}
catch (Exception Error)
{
    resultTextBox.Text = Error.Message;
}
```

Comment: So what kind of values are you getting in your first and secondText box . Is it multiple numbers or just one.

Comment: How are users entering the numbers into the text box? Any separator?

Comment: @Arran Yes i need to figure out how to  input the values separated by a coma.

Comment: You say two arrays, but there is only one?

Comment: you have a "foreach (char c..." loop and you are surprised that it reads as 4 and 9 and not 49?

Comment: @RyanSchlueter Multiple numbers

Comment: @Meta-Knight I'm not suprised I can't figure out another way to do it.

Comment: @ХристоХристов: The first question you should ask is how to split integer values separated by a comma in a textbox. And this question has been answered many times on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char separator=',';
int temp=-1;
var list1=firstTextBox.Split(new char[]{separator})
                      .Where(n=>int.TryParse(n,out temp))
                      .Select(n=>temp);
var list2=secondTextBox.Split(new char[]{separator})
                      .Where(n=>int.TryParse(n,out temp))
                      .Select(n=>temp);
var common=list1.Intersect(list2);
```

Comment: Hey to what does n refer to in this lambda expression?I understand i and s but n is quite new to me

Comment: @ХристоХристов n is a parameter..In this case it is a string

Answer (score 0):

If they are comma delimited then split the string and then loop through the array

```
char[] split = new char[] { ',' };
StringSplitOptions options = StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries;

string[] first = ConjTextBox.Text.Split(split, options);
string[] second = DisjTextBox.Text.Split(split, options);

int[] intsInFirstTextBox = Array.ConvertAll(first, s => int.Parse(s));
int[] intsInSecondTextBox = Array.ConvertAll(second, s => int.Parse(s));

int[] ListOfInts = intsInFirstTextBox.Intersect(intsInSecondTextBox);
```

Comment: Hey I'am really thankful for your response can you please explain me why are you making an array of the "split" char?

Comment: just for easy reference since it's used twice